# hibernate: how to setup on-delete="cascade" in one-to-one relation

Tags: hibernate, orm

i have to table relation one-to-one: message & scheduled_message

my hibernate config

```
<class name="Message" table="message">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" />
            <one-to-one name="scheduled">
</class>

<class name="ScheduledMessage" table="scheduled_message">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="startTime" column="start_time" />
    <property name="stopTime" column="stop_time" />
    <many-to-one name="message" column="message_id"
        unique="true" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

i want when message is deleted, scheduled_message is deleted too, but i dont know how to add on-delete="cascade" to this relation.

please help me

thanks

Quan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) say that `<one-to-one>` supports the `cascade` atribute. So:

```
<one-to-one name="scheduled" cascade="delete" .... />
```

Comment: i only search on-delete="cascade", hehe. Thank you

Comment: on-delete="cascade" and cascade="delete" has nothing in common!

Comment: well, they have. They are the two sides of one thing. One says what happens on delete, and the other says when to cascade.